# String Append in Java from Date without "-" to date with "-"

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I have a string "20180101" and need to append "-" after "2018" and "01" and "01" so it looks like "2018-01-01". Is there any standard way in Java to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the result is a String I just can suggest to use `replaceAll` which use a regex for example :

```
String date = "20180101";
date = date.replaceAll("(....)(..)(..)", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Or

```
date = date.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

Comment: @kumesana this is correct you can also use this `date = String.format("%s-%s-%s", date.substring(0, 4), date.substring(4, 6), date.substring(6, 8));`

Answer (score 8):

```
LocalDate.parse(
    "20180101", 
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-01-01

## Details

That string looks like a date. I suggest you to parse it into a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Your input string format `uuuuMMdd` is the “basic” variant of standard ISO 8601. The *java.time* classes have pre-defined an object for that formatting pattern, [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

That class generates a `String` by default in your desired format, the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("20180101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
String output = localDate.toString();  // the default format is the format you want.
```

> 2018-01-01

The above is a bit costly in performance, so here's a straightforward approach with [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("20180101");
sb.insert(6, "-");
sb.insert(4, "-");
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: I don't want to convert into a date. I want to convert into a string

Comment: you probably should add comment that parsing date format is costly in peformance terms.

Comment: Don’t be worried about performance. Or if you are, at least conduct tests to determine (1) whether performance is an issue (2) where in your code time is spent, before embarking on changing your code to be more fragile and less readable. Also, except for small throw-away programs you should get your data modelling right. This includes using a date class for dates.

Comment: @OleV.V. Edited.